# JavaFX TableView invert rows and columns

Tags: properties, javafx, tableview

Is there any reasonably simple way to invert the rows and columns in a TableView, so that columns are horizontal? I am using a TableView to display and edit some properties of an object, where one column holds the property keys and the other one (mostly editable) values.

The solution I have now is cumbersome, since I can not use TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn() for example since different rows need different cell types. Also if I want one property not to be editable through the table, I somehow need to explicitly change that in the CellFactory.

The picture below is correct, and it works, but with code that is too complicated and hard to maintain. I want the same thing but with different CellFactories for each row.

[image: How the table is supposed to look]

Comment: Maybe the [SpreadsheetView](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#spreadsheetview) of ControlsFX will fit your requirements?

Comment: @NwDx It looks promising, thank you! I will give it a shot!